# Retriving a row from database for suggestions

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which will input data from database and print it. Now at the customer name, i want an autosuggestion from the list of customer which are already in database. Eg when i start typing it should start suggesting the list of customer names which are stored in database. This is my current code for that text box.

```
<td valign="top"><div align="right">Enter Customer Name :</div></td>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">
            <input name="customername" class="gentxt" id="customername" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?php echo $customername; ?>" >
            </div></td>
```

Comment: Hmmm, you have to pull data from the database using SQL Query. But for start, show your code on your question, your db structure etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coderiddles.com/codeigniter-fetch-data-from-database/

Go through  this link you will get idea how to retrieve the data form database

Happy Coding :)